# How do I use the markdown module to print the module README.md file?

Tags: input-formats

I've created a README.md file in the custom module and would like to provide this as the help page in formatted HTML.

Raw text is being printed out, how do I get the HTML?

The module is drupal/markdown 3.0.0-rc1.

```
function cbi_bond_id_help($route_name, RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
  switch ($route_name) {
   case 'help.page.cbi_bond_id':
      $text = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . "/README.md");
      if (!\Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('markdown')) {
        return '<pre>' . $text . '</pre>';
      }
      else {
        // Use the Markdown filter to render the README.
        $filter_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.filter');
        $settings = \Drupal::configFactory()
          ->get('markdown.settings')
          ->getRawData();
        $config = ['settings' => $settings];
        $filter = $filter_manager->createInstance('markdown', $config);
        $filterResult =  $filter->process($text, 'en');
        $text = $filterResult->getProcessedText();
          return '<div>' . $text->getHtml() . '</div>';
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tinkered a bit with your code and I believe that your parser settings are modifying your output. I was able to read in a markdown file and output it correctly, formatted as HTML, using the `\Drupal\markdown\PluginManager\ParserManager` service and setting the render strategy to `none`.

```
$text = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . "/README.md");
if (!\Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('markdown')) {
  return '<pre>' . $text . '</pre>';
}
else {
  /** @var \Drupal\markdown\PluginManager\ParserManagerInterface $parser_manager */
  $parser_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.markdown.parser');
  $parser = $parser_manager->getDefaultParser([
    'render_strategy' => ['type' => 'none'],
  ]);
  return $parser->parse($text);
}
```